# Taking long time to load selectBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Below code snippet, "**for**" loop is taking long time to load the data to select box, could any one help me ? even I am using Jquery 1.3.2 which is new to me.

here names.response.length is 120000 records.

```
function personNameChangedCallback(names){
 if(names.response.length > 0){
    var options = [];

   for (var i = 0; i< names.response.length; i++) {
        options.push('<option>'+ names.response[i] +'</option>');
    }
 jQuery('[id=personNameSelected]').append(options.join(''));
}
```

Comment: Of course it is, 120000 is a crazy number of elements to render

Comment: I would suggest looking into implementing an autosuggest/autocomplete plugin, and don't show that many results

Comment: It is working fine Chrome, but it is taking long time in IE

Comment: That select is useless with that many options.

Comment: I agree with @Taplar and epascrello, think about that poor user who is gonna have to select from those options

Comment: I have done the below changes, now three time performance increased.     
                                                                                                                       
     for (var i = 0; i< names.response.length; i++) {                                        
      var opt = names.response[i]; var el = document.createElement("option"); 
     el.textContent = opt; el.value = opt; document.getElementById("personNameSelected").appendChild(el); }

Comment: You really need to use such an old version of jQuery? Also why don't you use `$(#personNameSelected)`? Both this things wont solve the performance issue though.

Comment: why dont you render the select server-side?

Answer (score 1):

What could help is to avoid using an array to store the options and instead concatenate the strings directly.

Here is a jsperf comparison for this, using array is around 80% slower than directly concatenating a string:
https://jsperf.com/javascript-test-string-concat-vs-array/1

So you can change your function like this:

```
function personNameChangedCallback(names){
 if(names.response.length > 0){
    var htmlOptions = '';

   for (var i = 0; i< names.response.length; i++) {
        htmlOptions += '<option>'+ names.response[i] +'</option>';
    }
 jQuery('[id=personNameSelected]').html(htmlOptions);
}
```

The reason why it is slow in Internet Explorer, is because it's Javascript engine is not as advanced as the ones of other browsers. 
Internet Explorer will also have issues letting you scroll through all these options. 
Using a suggestion box as already mentioned by someone else is a better option, especially when your applciation has to be compatible with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Reto, I fixed this. I am appending 10000 each time and it is working fine,implemented big data algorithm.